# css-loader ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve the file path

Tags: webpack, css-loader, less-loader

Please help me resolve ModuleNotFoundError when i try to import assets to my .less file.

Looks like the issue is will css-loader, can someone help me in gracefully resolving the issue.

Link to issue on git hub:https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/682

Please find

- variables.less
- common.less
- webpack.config.js
- error log

**common.less**

```
@import "variables.less";
// Global Styles
* {
    outline: none !important;
}

body {
    background: @sidebar;
    font-family: @basefont1;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    color: @bodytext;
    font-weight: 300;
}







**variables.less**

//Path of current-file 
///home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/libs/ample-admin/ampleadmin-minimal
// Variables
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:300,400,500,700,900);
@import "icons/font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less";

@basefont1:'Rubik', sans-serif;
@basefont2:'Rubik', sans-serif;
```

**webpack.conif.js**

```
{
            test: /\.less$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                use: [{
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'less-loader',
                        options: {
                            paths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")],
                        }
                    }
                ],
                fallback: 'style-loader'
                // ,publicPath:publicPath_Css
            })
        }
```

**Error-Log**

```
ERROR in ./libs/ample-admin/ampleadmin-minimal/less/common.less
Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './icons/font-awesome/less/icons/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot' in '/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/libs/ample-admin/ampleadmin-minimal/less'
    at factoryCallback (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:276:40)
    at factory (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:237:20)
    at resolver (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:60:20)
    at asyncLib.parallel.e (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:127:20)
    at /home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3874:9
    at /home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
    at iteratorCallback (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1048:13)
    at /home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:958:16
    at /home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3871:13
    at resolvers.normal.resolve (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:119:22)
    at onError (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:65:10)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
    at /home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:40:4
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
    at innerCallback (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:144:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:249:35)
    at resolver.doResolve.createInnerCallback (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:44:6)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at afterInnerCallback (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:168:10)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/sujeet/projects/src/module-front/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
 @ ./libs/ample-admin/ampleadmin-minimal/less/common.less
 @ ./src/apps/home/home.app.js
```